# CSS3 Parse Error Lexical error

Tags: css, validation, parse-error

I keep getting this error and am not sure why it pops up when I validate it. Can anyone explain this to me and how to fix it? The error is this: 
246  #copyright  Parse Error Lexical error at line 249, column 2. Encountered: " " (32), after : "@"

Here is the code. I am starting with line 246, which I guess where it starts...not really understanding what is going on here. Line 246 is the closing bracket for my smartphone css. I can post that also if you need it. Much appreciated.

```
}
/* ----- Tablet ----- */
@ media screen (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 769px) {
   div#wrapper{
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1em;
      width: 98%;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the parser encountered a space " " after the "@" following line 246. The space is not supposed to be there, hence the parse error; you need to remove it.

You are also missing an `and` from this media query.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 769px) {
```

Comment: Thank, I am going to try this out and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any space between @ and media.

It should be :

```
@media //not @ media
```